# Node.js - createWriteStream is writing a different file than writeFile

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm trying to download an MP4 file remotely using an HTTP GET request. When the HTTP GET response is being pipped to the file, the file is being written perfectly (~3MB).

```
request.get('http://url.tld/video.mp4').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('video.mp4'))
```

However, when the HTTP GET response body is being written by the `fs.writeFileSync` function, it creates a larger file (~7MB) and it can't be executed since it damaged.

```
request.get('http://url.tld/video.mp4', function(err, res, body){
    fs.writeFileSync('./video.mp4', body)
});
```

Why does it happen ? Does the pipe function sets the right encoding for the corresponding file ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is the encoding. While writing to file instead of piping to stream, the body stream is converted to Buffer object with `utf8` encoding before written to file.

Just a simple experiment to prove this.

**Check the length of the downloaded stream**

```
var streamlen = 0;

request.get('http://url.tld/video.mp4')
.on('data', function(data){
    streamlen = streamlen + data.length;
})
.on('end',function(){
   console.log("Downloaded stream length is: " + streamlen);
})

//This should output your actual size of the mp4 file
```

**Check the length of the body**

```
request.get('http://url.tld/video.mp4', function(err, res, body){
    console.log("The body length of the response in utf8 is: " + Buffer.from(body).length);
    console.log("The body length of the response in ascii is: " + Buffer.from(body,'ascii').length);
});

//This would be approximately double in utf8 and a little less than original bytes in ascii
```

**NOTE:**

It's not that piping does the right encoding, its just that piping doesn't do encoding. It just passes the stream as it is.

Comment: It seems like the problem is the response body type. It's a String instead of Buffer.

Comment: Yeah. But I couldn't figure out unless I debugged the reverse way. It is easier to prove by contradiction rather than reading out the whole `request` library :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that by getting a response as follows, the `body` type is a UTF-8 String Encoded instead of a Buffer.

```
request.get('http://url.tld/video.mp4', function(err, res, body){
        fs.writeFileSync('./video.mp4', body)
    });
```

According to request library documentation:

> encoding - Encoding to be used on setEncoding of response data. If
>   null, the body is returned as a Buffer. Anything else (including the
>   default value of undefined) will be passed as the encoding parameter
>   to toString() (meaning this is effectively utf8 by default). (Note: if
>   you expect binary data, you should set encoding: null.)

The solution would be to pass an 'encoding' argument to the options object in the request as follows:

```
request.get('http://url.tld/video.mp4', {encoding: null}, function(err, res, body){
    fs.writeFileSync('./video.mp4', body)
});
```