# Does Node.js fs.createWriteStream(downloadDirectory) creates file on the server file systems or on the user's device?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, filesystems, fs, gridfs

I'm trying to download files from MongoDB to the user's device (the user's local file system).

I'm using Gridfs-stream to create a readStream to read files from MongoDB, and pipe it into Node.js fs.createWriteStream(downloadDirectory) (downloadDirectory is the directory the user wanted it to be).

Now, I'm coding on localhost, so it downloads to wherever I point it to.

My question is: after I deployed my backend and frontend, is my approach going to download the file to the ***downloadDirectory*** on my server or the ***downloadDirectory*** on the user's device?

```
        const readstream = gfs.createReadStream({
          _id: file._id
        })

        const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(downloadDirectory + file.name)

        const writeStream = readstream.pipe(fileStream)

        writeStream.on('finish', (returnedFile) => {
            res.json(returnedFile)
        })
```

**Solution:**

I spent over 12 hours debugging how to download attachment files from the Node.js server on the client-side.

This post saved my life.
[Node.js - createWriteStream is writing a different file than writeFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41791202/node-js-createwritestream-is-writing-a-different-file-than-writefile)

For those of you who are still struggling on can't open a downloaded attachment or downloaded file doubled the size and corrupted. Check the ***Encoding***!